# What are Sideband Pulses?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer

I asked this question on Quantum Computing SE about a month ago and haven't gotten any answers https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15646/what-are-sideband-pulses. Was hoping someone here might have an answer.

I see sideband pulses used all over the place when looking up implementation techniques especially in Trapped Ion QC. Is there a layman's explanation of what they actually are? I understand what they do in terms of Energy Transitions, and how that is then used for gates; but I am struggling with understanding how these pulses can be tweaked to do nearly everything (In the case of the Cirac-Zoller Gate for instance).

My reference text has been Nielsen and Chuang, where they introduce sideband pulses in chapter 7.6; just for some context on where I am.

Comment: What *do* you know - say, about quantum optics? I think you'll have to clearly state *what* you understand about them and what your question precisely is.